# Can't lengthen a field in a dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

I had a dataset taxes that is used in a windows form project. 'tax_id' int64 primary key, 'Tax' string 20 chr, 'type' string 2 and it's used on a form. Then I found I needed to change the type to 5 chars. So I do this in an sql database and in the dataset in properties I change the MaxLength from 2 to 5 characters. Now when I save a change on the form it only saves the first 2 characters. Why? How do I get it to save all 5 characters.

Here is code,

```
TaxDataTableAdapters.TaxTableAdapter taxConnect = new TaxDataTableAdapters.TaxTableAdapter();
taxConnect.UpdateTaxData(taxTextBox.Text, typeTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt64(tax_idTextBox.Text));
```

The code only saves the first two characters of typeTextBox.Text. It's now 5 character long, after changing the database and dataset.

Comment: Please show the piece of code you're having problems with.

Comment: See example code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. I find that I can only saves the first 2 characters to database even if I changed the maxlength to 5.

After my attempt, I find the way to solve it.

First, please change update your field in your database table to nvarchar(5).

Then, please add the Dataset again.

Finally, I can use the same code to get the correct data.

```
 TestDataSetTableAdapters.TaxesTableAdapter adapter = new TestDataSetTableAdapters.TaxesTableAdapter();
 adapter.UpdateQuery(1001, "test", "t9999", 1001, "test", "t6");
```

[image]

Comment: I've discovered I can readd the dataset to correct the problem( just delete the tabaleadapter and reenter it), but this is in a big program. I have 50 queries in this dataset, with the one displayed above being one. I was hoping for a solution where I didn't need to add the dataset back again.